# How to get the value of previous and current profile assigned to a user using trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I do have a requirement like I need to write a trigger on user object.The trigger must be before update, which should give the value of previous and current profile assigend to a user.

any help??

This is what I have done, but not getting anything in debug log

```
trigger UserProfileTrigger on User (before update) {

for(Integer i = 0; i< Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
        if(Trigger.new[i].Profile!= Trigger.old[i].Profile){
         System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.old is: ' + Trigger.old[i].profile);
         System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.new is: ' + Trigger.new[i].profile); 
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field within the User object is ProfileId, not profile.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is we have to use profileId instead of profile. Thanks to FrankZ

```
 trigger UserProfileTrigger on User (before update) {

        for(Integer i = 0; i< Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
                if(Trigger.new[i].ProfileId!= Trigger.old[i].ProfileId){
                 System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.old is: ' + Trigger.old[i].profileId);
                 System.debug('***SFDC: Trigger.new is: ' + Trigger.new[i].profileId); 
                 }
            }
        }
```