# How to get the list of all the users whose profile has changed?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a requirement that i want to fetch the list of all the users whose profile has changed from object user.

Say I've 3 users in my user obejct.I wrote the following code, in which I have craeted a list and put all users.But how to check which user's profile is changed and assign it in a collection?

Following is my code:

```
trigger UserProfileTrigger on User (before update) {

    List<user> usr = [SELECT Id,Name,Username,ProfileId FROM User];
    System.debug('***SFDC: User Details: ' + usr );

    for (User u: usr){
       System.debug('***SFDC: User is: '+u);
        how to write logic for comparing new and old value of profileid for each user?
}
```

Comment: Not sure about your question. Your code shows an APEX trigger which is called before update. In this case you can compare the ProfileId fields of the Users in trigger.old with those in trigger.new. But I guess I had answered that already in your previous question.

Comment: @FrankZ : In last comment you told me how to deal with single request. i.e : 
'if(Trigger.new[i] != Trigger.old[i]){
   //TODO
}'

But here we are dealing with so many requests.

Let's say I have 3 users, and I am trying to update User's Profile for 2 users. So I want to display only those 2 users in my debug list.

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/21010/4505 - The for loop goes through all updated records.

Comment: @FrankZ: Yeah the answer you have given is perfect, but I was looking for the answer in different approach. Instead of 
for(Integer i = 0; i< Trigger.new.size(); i++) I was looking for(User u : Trigger.new) this type of approach. I found my solution, thnx for your help.